# managing keyboard layouts outside unity

Tags: unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus, fluxbox

I would like to know if there is any way of using the standard ubuntu keyboard layouts from outside Unity. I am using a different WM (Fluxbox).

The brute force approach would be to use xkb. I can do. But, before I go down that route, I'd like to explore other options. I have tried running the ibus-daemon directly which seems to work, but the keyboard layouts it offers are different from the standard ubuntu ones (and there are much less of them).

I noticed that i can't just run

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-keyboard/indicator-keyboard-service &
```

Any ideas?

The Ubuntu version is 15.10.

Comment: I do not have the access from Fluxbox to a indicator-keyboard systray applet (it appears there is no equivalent of 'nm-applet' in this case). The alternative is to run an ibus-daemon instance which installs it's own (uglier) systray applet with only a limited choice of keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've decided to stop the impossible and pull out pieces of Unity into Fluxbox. Instead, there is a much more fluxboxy solution, indeed relying on setxkbmap. With reference to [this unix stack exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52391/fluxbox-keyboard-switch-german-greek-modern-and-polytonic-greek) I have made a similar submenu setup for Serbian (Latin) and German on an US keyboard.

In .fluxbox/menu,

```
[begin] (fluxbox)
[include] (/etc/X11/fluxbox/fluxbox-menu)
[submenu] (keyboards)
[exec] (us) {setxkbmap us}
[exec] (de) {setxkbmap de qwerty}
[exec] (rs) {setxkbmap rs latinunicodeyz}
[end]
```

the preceding snippet sets up three items corresponding to  different keyboard layouts.

To make things more flexible, i have also added keyboard shortcuts in .fluxbox/keys,

```
Mod4 Shift 1 :Exec chkb.sh us
Mod4 Shift 2 :Exec chkb.sh rs latinunicodeyz
Mod4 Shift 3 :Exec chkb.sh de qwerty
```

where chkb.sh is a script with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash    
langsel="$1"
varant="$2"
setxkbmap "$1" "$2"
xmodmap "/home/user/.Xmodmap"
```

. Since I am an Emacs user, I prefer to bind Caps Lock to Ctrl functionality (and Ctrl to Caps Lock) , and each time I change the  keyboard layout, I need to repeat the binding process by rereading the .Xmodmap definition. This is nicer if packed into a script, than called directly by the :Exec directive.

Maybe someone still has a different solution...